# On the definition of the Minkowski sum

Tags: convex-analysis, sumset

> Closed sets need not be mapped to closed sets by the Minkowski sum as the following example shows:
> $$ S_1 := \{ (x, y) \mid x, y \in \Bbb R, x \geq 0, x y \geq 1 \},$$
> $$ S_2 := {\Bbb R} \times \{0\} $$
> and
> $$ S_1 + S_2 = \{ (x,y) \mid x \in {\Bbb R}, y > 0 \} $$

---

Here on the above example, I don't quite understand the definition of such a set,
and the consequence of the Minkowski sum. Could you please help me to figure this out?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevado Please don't make purely cosmetic edits to old questions. They move to the active question queue and distract folks who follow that queue.

Comment: What is the source of the screenshot?

Comment: @EthanBolker Transcribing screenshots is not purely cosmetic

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Fair point. The edit I saw was just the case changes in the title.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yeah, the transcription took a couple of minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of sum of two set is usually taken to be

$$S_1+S_2=\{s_1+s_2\mid s_1\in S_1,  s_2\in S_2\}$$

Which is the set of all possible sums where you take one element from each set and add them.

To see why they are the same. Take any $(x,y)$ where $y>0$, rewrite it as $(\frac 1y + (x-\frac 1y), y)=(\frac 1y,y) + (x-\frac 1y,0)$, where the first point is in $S_1$ and second point is in $S_2$. This shows that $\{(x,y)\mid x\in \mathbb R, y>0\} \subset S_1+S_2$. Similarly you can prove the other inclusion, thus showing the two sets are equivalent.

Comment: Great. Now I understand that the minkowski sum of two closed sets doesn't guarantee to be a closed set with your help!

This was used to show that the infimal convolution doesn't guarantee to preserve lower semi-continuity of two lsc. functions.

Answer (score 0):

The product of sets is

$$ A \times B = \{ (a,b) \mid a \in A, b \in B \} $$

therefore

$$ \mathbb{R} \times \{ 0 \} = \{ (a,0) \mid a \in \mathbb{R} \} $$

Comment: Thanks ;) It was helpful.